# web api odata action method to return image

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

We are using asp.net web api odata entitysetcontroller to get user profiles. The url that represents a single user profile looks like this

http://www.domain.com/api/org/staff(123)

Now bussiness asked us to provide user image as part of the user profile.  So I added a odata action method to the exisitng controller.

```
var staff = builder.EntitySet<Contact>("staff");  //regiester controller
var staffAction = staff.EntityType.Action("picture");  //register action method          
staffAction.Returns<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>();
```

The odata action method in controller as below

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Picture([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        var folderName = "App_Data/Koala.jpg";
        string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName);

        using (FileStream mem = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open))
        {
            StreamContent sc = new StreamContent(mem);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();                
            response.Content = sc;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = mem.Length;
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return response;
        }
    }
```

I tried the following url to test and the method executed successfully. However the problem is that I always recieve the error message with status 504 as a final response.

http://www.domain.com/api/org/staff(123)/picture

```
"ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with *closing* the FileStream.

Do not close the stream as Web API's hosting layers take care of closing it. Also, you need 
not set the content-length explicitly.StreamContent sets this for you.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Picture([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var folderName = "App_Data/Koala.jpg";
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName);

    StreamContent sc = new StreamContent(new FileStream(path,FileMode.OpenRead));
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();                
        response.Content = sc;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return response;
}
```

Comment: @Kiran-Challa What about uploading files? I couldn't find any good example for doing this with wep api odata

Comment: I've got the same question as @CoffeeCode. What are you doing for upload? Not finding great examples on the web. Thanks.